# How to choose saving directory with python-pptx?

Tags: python, directory, save, python-pptx

I'm pretty new to python and I've been working on a project with pptx python.
Everything is fine, but I don't understand how to choose in which directory my file will be saved.

Here is my code:

```
from pptx import Presentation
prs = Presentation()
title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[0]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
title = slide.shapes.title
subtitle = slide.placeholders[1]

title.text = "Hello, World!"
subtitle.text = "python-pptx was here!"

prs.save('test.pptx')
```

It will save the document on my desktop. How can I choose the directory ?

Thanks in advance!
PS : I'm using python 3.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me guess - the python script is on the Desktop too!

`prs.save('test.pptx')` is a relative path. So test.pptx will be stored in the same directory as your script. If you want another location, use an absolute path, like `prs.save('C:/Users/xyz/Desktop/data/test.pptx')`

[This Link may be helpful too! ;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44772007/when-to-use-absolute-path-vs-relative-path-in-python)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The absolute path is the notion I needed as I made a pptx factory which has to save pptx in differents folders.

Answer (score 1):

```
def save(self, path_or_stream):
    """
    Save this presentation package to *path_or_stream*, which can be
    either a path to a filesystem location (a string) or a file-like
    object. for example save(self, 'C:\mypath'):
    """
    self.package.save(path_or_stream)
```