# FileNotFoundError in Python Visul Studio

Tags: python, filenotfounderror

I get this when I try to run my python project code

```py
with open("config.json", "r") as f:
```

Exception raised:

```py
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'config.json'
```

what is a solution for this?

[here is a screenshot of the code and everything.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQBx5.png)

Comment: `config.json` file needs to be located with your python code in a same folder. Can you show us how the json file and your python code are located now?

Comment: try use absolute full name instead of relative name.

Comment: @SangkeunPark here is a screenshot of the code https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMy7y.png

Comment: @LeiYang can you explain more about it?

Comment: `open("C:/some path/config.json")`

Comment: @tareq Please upload the image to your question, not in a comment, so that other people can see.

Answer (score 2):

the file config.jason needs to be in your current working directory to be found by open if you do not use a full path.  Your cwd is probably where you launched python.  To check do

```
    import os
    print(os.getcwd())
```

Your easiest solution is probably to use a full path name for the file.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the screenshot of the IDE, you should exactly point out where the .json file. Now the json file and python code are not located in the same folder.

FYI, there are two types of path, absolute path and relative path. Please see https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-find-the-absolute-and-relative-path-of-a-file-in-pythonhttps://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-find-the-absolute-and-relative-path-of-a-file-in-python

```py
with open("/file program/config.json", "r") as f
    content = f.read()
    # do something
```

Or, just move out the `config.json` file to the folder, which the python code is located.

Comment: I did what you say to put the .json file in the same folder as where python code is located like this https://imgur.com/a/9ulb9OU and now I get this issue in my terminal https://imgur.com/a/W9Te01U

Comment: Where is `bot.py`? The image showes that there is no `bot.py` at C:\Users\97154\Desktop\EinsteinBot-master (1)\EinsteinBot-master.

Comment: I have it here.. https://imgur.com/a/9ulb9OU ... whats the problem then?

Comment: @tareq Now it is good to locate the two file in a same folder. Then, you have to run the bot.py at `C:\Users\97154\Desktop\EinsteinBot-master (1)\EinsteinBot-master\file program` because you move `bot.py` to the folder.

Comment: yes I did it, I had to do cd "filename" I did it here and now Im having this cogs issue https://imgur.com/a/q0Q47Ec
(I changed "EinsteinBot-master" file name to "chegg" )
here is the code for cogs https://imgur.com/a/O9qrAg2

Comment: @tareq That is because you moved the `bot.py` to another folder so your code cannot find the `.cogs` path in the new folder. It is very necessary to understand a concept of `absolute path` and `relative path` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44772007/when-to-use-absolute-path-vs-relative-path-in-python), then you will realize why the issue happens. :)

Comment: @tareq did you solve the issue?